# whats the difference between cv::equalizeHist and matlab histeq()

Tags: c++, opencv, matlab

Very simple question, but i am confused in it. Can anybody explain Is there any difference between Matlab histeq() function and Opencv cv::equalizeHist() function.

As i am trying to apply histogram equalization in matlab on an image, but i found out that the result is not same, there is a difference of about 4-6 in each value of the pixel. Specially the first 2 pixels of a row. and than 1 or 2 difference in other pixels. 
e.g for the same image
openCV results in

100,160,210,240

But Matlab returns

97, 159, 210, 240.

even i tried to use histeq(image,255);  or histeq(image,256); but even than its the same. Whats the difference?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It might resides in the fact that Matlab uses a constraint that specify that the grayscale transformation cannot overshoot the cumulative histogram of your image by more than half the distance between the histogram counts for a given intensity. You have more details on the algorithms used by Matlab [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) (at the bottom of the page, under "Algorithm'), and OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok so they are not exactly the same. Now how can i get the result similar to opencv. Or does i have to do coding by self. Is there a built in function or a code available for that anywhere in matlab?

Comment: Matlab has a forum for user-submitted code called [FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). You can search there for other implementation. But actually why not use the Matlab results directly?

Comment: I tried to wrote a opencv code in matlab. same as it is. But still the result is not as opencv. So after thoroughly checking of the code and all the inputs and outputs one of the reason (or difference in opencv inputOutputs ) is the output of this histeq() function. the code is for neural networks. so preprocessing is an important step in it. So i thought may be the result diffenrece is due to the preprocessed data difference..

Comment: Whether that difference is the cause for your different results when applying neural network is another question, that unfortunately I cannot help you with.

Comment: I can understand. THank you so much. i am trying to figure it. I think that is not a big problem currently.Seems some other problem....

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's histeq function gives you a couple input options 1) `J = histeq(I, hgram)` - output J will approximate a user-specified histogram and 2) `J = histeq(I, n)` - output J will approximate the default flat histogram but with n discrete gray levels. If n is omitted, the default number of gray levels is 64. OpenCV's equalizeHist(src, dst) doesn't give you either of these options; it turns out that it assume 256 gray levels. So if you try `J = histeq(I, 256)`, your result will match opencv.